# Alphabetize index subentries with references

Tags: cross-referencing, indexing

I'm able to print an index alphabetically. However, if I use \ref in the index entry, the subentries are not in alphabetical order. I'd like Module 3 entry to come after Module 2 entry. How can I tell LaTeX to sort/alphabetize by the chapter number rather than chapter name?

[image: MWE index subentry alphabetical issue]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\def\usletterpaper{\usepackage[bottom=1in,hmarginratio=1:1,letterpaper]{geometry}}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Node Management} \label{chap:NodeMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check}
\index{Learning Check!Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\index{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}@Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{User Management} \label{chap:UserMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check} 
\index{Learning Check!Module~\ref{chap:UserMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\index{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:UserMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\
Question\\
Answer\\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Application Management} \label{chap:AppMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check}
\index{Learning Check!Module \ref{chap:AppMgmt} @Module~\thechapter}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\index{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:AppMgmt}@Module\ref{chap:AppMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `\ref`s are not expanded when send to the `.idx` file.
Therefore, the entries are not ordered by the numbers but by the content of `\ref`, the first one being `\ref{chap:AppMgmt}`, which will result in Module 3 in the end.

What must be done is to expand the reference before sending it to the `.idx` file.
This can be done with `\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{\expandafter\index\expandafter{#1}}`.
Then changing every `\index` for `\myindex` will give the desired output.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{report}
\def\usletterpaper{\usepackage[bottom=1in,hmarginratio=1:1,letterpaper]{geometry}}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex


\newcommand{\myindex}[1]{\expandafter\index\expandafter{#1}}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Node Management} \label{chap:NodeMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check}
\myindex{Learning Check!Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\myindex{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}@Module~\ref{chap:NodeMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{User Management} \label{chap:UserMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check} 
\myindex{Learning Check!Module~\ref{chap:UserMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\myindex{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:UserMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\
Question\\
Answer\\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Application Management} \label{chap:AppMgmt}
Chapter text here.

\section{Learning Check}
\myindex{Learning Check!Module~\ref{chap:AppMgmt}@Module~\thechapter}
Question\\
Answer\\

\section{Learning Check Answer}
\myindex{Learning Check Answers!Module~\ref{chap:AppMgmt}@Module~\ref{chap:AppMgmt}}
Question\\
Answer\\

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: THanks Raoul. I let this one go and just now came back to it. Your logic makes total sense, but the command isn't working for me. Any other ideas?